# Prove $(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)(e^2 + f^2) \ge (ace + bdf)^2.$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,$ $b,$ $c,$ $d,$ $e,$ $f$ be nonnegative real numbers. Prove that
$$(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)(e^2 + f^2) \ge (ace + bdf)^2.$$

---

I know $(a^2+b^2)(c^2e^2+d^2f^2)\ge (ace+bdf)^2$ by Cauchy, but I'm having trouble on what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Comment: Well, why don't you try to check if $(c^2+d^2)(e^2+f^2)\ge (c^2e^2+d^2f^2)$ then?

Comment: Thanks!!! I got it!

Comment: HINT.-The set of sums of two squares is closed by multiplication:

$$ (a^2 + b^2) ( c^2 + d^2) = (ac + bd)^2 + (ad - bc)^2$$ so you can reduce the LHS to a sum of two squares multiplying $[(ac + bd)^2 + (ad - bc)^2](e^2+f^2)$ then choose the fit  in an easier manner.